# Angular Js : How to find first and last element in ng-repeat and add special class to them?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I changed the following using angular js

```
<section id="social">
    <h2 class="line">Social Profiles</h2>
    <a href="#" class="first"><i class="icon-facebook"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="icon-twitter"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="icon-linkedin"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="icon-google-plus"></i></a>
    <a href="#" class="last"><i class="icon-rss"></i></a>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</section>
```

To this

```
<section id="social">
    <h2 class="line">Social Profiles</h2>
    <a ng-repeat="sMedia in socialMedia" ng-if="$first" href="#" >
        <i class="{{sMedia.icon}}"></i>
    </a>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</section>
```

Everything seems fine except I could not find a way to add `class="first"` in the first element and `class="last"` in the last element of `ng-repeat`.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Just use $first and $last combined with ng-class:

```
<a ng-repeat="sMedia in socialMedia" ng-class="{'first': $first, 'last': $last}" href="#" >
```

See here how they work: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```
#social a:first-child{ /* your first css code */ }
#social a:last-child{ /* your last css code */ }
```

Comment: Doesn't work as you might expect if .ng-hide class is applied on the first and/or last element as :first-child/:last-child doesn't concern itself with whether the element is rendered on screen or not, but whether it is literally the first or last element within the set in markup.  http://fiddle.jshell.net/p5qe82w4/4/

Comment: @KerryJohnson That's true, but it's not in the scope of question. This answer works great for what was asked. (saying this just in case you thought this answer was bad)

Comment: @Shomz I disagree.  He asked how to add his own class to the first and last element within ng-repeat, not asking if there was a pseudo-class selector to select the first and last class.  Since this answer was upvoted some, I am simply detailing the caveat of this answer and likely the reason many of us are here to begin with (to avoid that caveat).

Comment: @KerryJohnson I meant that `ng-hide` was never mentioned in the question and if the whole purpose of what's in the question was to just add CSS rules to the first and last element, then this answer works, that's why I upvoted it. But I agree with you, for many other causes, it won't work.

Comment: @Shomz For sure.  I arrived here specifically looking to see if there was a way to programmatically add a custom class to the first and last visible elements in an ng-repeat because pseudo-class targeting is too basic at times.  Looking at his code it seems he just didn't know about the CSS approach.  I voted the other solution because it answered the question about adding custom classes which is exactly what I need.  Both answers can lead to the desired outcome, but I was just letting know that the CSS approach can be troublesome in the Angular context especially when ng-hide is applied. :)

Comment: Yup, I understand, and your input is very useful and much appreciated because I'm sure more people would look to combine `ng-class` with `ng-hide`! I just wanted to make sure we agree that neither his answer nor my answer are wrong for this question. And we clearly agree :)